# Importing local files on tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, networking, tampermonkey

I want to record the network traffic on a website. I found that serviceWorker can intercept fetch calls thus I need to write a tampermonkey script that registers a serviceWorker on the website when it loads and then I can run code to record the traffic inside fetch event handler.

The serviceWorker code needs to be written on a separate js file and that file is registered in the website with the following code:

```
if(navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('filename.js');
}
```

So I thought to write the serviceWorker code as a separate js file in my computer and then importing this file inside the tampermonkey script using the `@require` tag.

```
// @require      file:///D:/Javascript/test.js
```

This url when typed in the browser opens the file properly but tampermonkey is not able to load this file when I try to register with `navigator.serviceWorker.register('test.js'`). I checked the browser console and the following error was thrown:

```
Tampermonkey: couldn't load @require from URL file:///D:/Javascript/test.js
eval @ chrome-extension://d…bdd7-3437a7188621:2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making a github respitory and putting the code in a file in the repo, then do something like so in your tampermonkey script:

```
// @require     https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/usernamerhere/respitorynamehere@latest/filenamehere.min.js

// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
```

then do something like:

````
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method : "GET",
        url : "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/yourgithubnameherereponame@latest/filenamehere.min.js",
        onload : (ev) =>
        {
            let e = document.createElement('script');
            e.innerText = ev.responseText;
            document.head.appendChild(e);
        }
    });```
````